# Is it possible to install Desktop edition in Server edition, then access remotely?

Tags: server, remote-desktop

Is it possible to install Desktop edition in Server edition, then access remotely? I can think of lots of applications for this, but don't know if it's possible, or what the drawbacks could be.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by installing "Desktop edition in Server edition"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should install ubuntu-desktop and openssl-server

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop openssh-server
```

then use `ssh -X` to access your server remotely.

or you can follow [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-openssh-server-installation-and-configuration/) to config your ssl

Comment: Would I then be able to use the desktop remotely? Would I be limited in anyway to using an application like virtual box? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: yes, if your server is connected with WAN (means that your server has a IP address). 
You can use this commend: ssh -X <serverip>
or use gui remote desktop tools to access the server.

Answer (score 3):

As Petrie Wong noted you can install ubuntu-desktop on the server.  (This package is the desktop portion of the desktop edition.)  If you shutdown the desktop, you also shutdown the server.

You could also run the desktop edition in a virtual machine using KVM.  This would give some security separation between the server and desktop.  Shutting down the desktop would only kill the virtual machine and not the server.

Normal access of servers is over SSH using the openssh-server package.   Programs requiring a graphical interface can be accesses using display forwarding over ssh, and only require a minimal set of x-window programs.

On a server providing a remote desktop, it is common to use a light-weight window manager.  A workable desktop with VNC access can be created by installing the packages: xinetd, tightvncserver, xdm, and xfce4-server.  Windows remote desktop access can be provided by adding the xrdp package.  I documented my setup for [Remote Desktops with VNC and RDP](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/).

Comment: What I am trying to do is run virtual box on my server. I am an Ubuntu novice, but what I would like to use virtualbox for is to run windows, and then run quickbooks. Is this possible through the way you explained?

Comment: Yes,  I believe virtual box is packaged for Ubuntu.  You would then need to install Windows into an instance.  You should have an appropriate Windows license.  Check whether your version of Quickbooks is supported by Wine.  You could install a lightweight Ubuntu instance in Virtualbox or KVM with wine running.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean install the set of applications ( mostly gui ) that are installed by default in Desktop Edition, but not Server Edition, then just install the ubuntu-desktop package.

Answer (score 0):

if you wan to install a graphical desktop manager without some of the desktop addons like Evolution and OpenOffice, but continue to use the server flavor kernel use the following command

```
sudo aptitude install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```